# What alternative can be used for ExecCommand on ContentEditable?

Tags: javascript, events, contenteditable, wysiwyg, execcommand

So, I am trying to build a WYSIWYG editor and using `execCommand("bold")`, `execCommand("italic")` etc. While they work properly, the Docs says `execCommand` is deprecated and might start to not work anymore. However, it doesn't say what to use instead of it. Is there any alternative ?

I have tried:

```
window.dispatchEvent(
   new KeyboardEvent("keydown",{ctrlKey: true, code: "KeyB", keyCode: 66})
);
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't affect elements with `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: Syntax error, imbalanced quotes

Comment: I think the idea is to use the [selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), DOM manipulation, and (for relevant commands) [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) instead. That said, while MDN may mark it deprecated and browser developers may wish it to go away, its basic widely-supported features will almost certainly never do so, because of breaking existing code.